# Example or Documentation to implement Persistent Storage and Transactional Outbox in MassTransit?

Tags: ravendb, masstransit

I'm using RavenDb and would like to benefit from both persistent storage and Transactional Outbox.  I'm trying to figure out how this is implemented, but I can't find any documentation and looking through the code, it appears to be highly abstracted out.

Does anyone have any Tips or direction on how I could implement this?  RavenDb seems ideal in any event because it can push notifications automatically and does all of the clean up, so a mass transit integration seems like an excellent fit.

I did find an old persistence library that has been archived but it's for both a very old version of RavenDb and MassTransit and doesn't seem to be relevant and doesn't have Transactional Outbox.

Comment: You could probably use the MongoDB persistence library as a starting point, but there isn't documentation on how to build things like this as most are first-party.

Comment: Ya, that's the problem I found and it doesn't appear that there is clear separation of the MongoDb functionality to be able to just implement one part.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the latest version of [RavenDB](https://ravendb.net/), v6.0, does not support MassTransit integration.

However, [Kafka ETL](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/server/ongoing-tasks/etl/queue-etl/kafka), [Kafka Sink](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/server/ongoing-tasks/queue-sink/kafka-queue-sink), [RabbitMQ ETL](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/server/ongoing-tasks/etl/queue-etl/rabbit-mq), and [RabbitMQ Sink](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/server/ongoing-tasks/queue-sink/rabbit-mq-queue-sink) are supported.

Comment: It isn't about being a Sink. It's about being the persistence layer for SAGAs and Persistent Outbox which right now only Mongo and EF are supported, neither of which I can use.